# Cannot Edit Sql Agent Job Step in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I use SQL Server 2012 BI edition.

User has the following roles in the `MSDB` database:

- `SQLAgentOperatorRole`
- `SQLAgentReaderRole`
- `SQLAgentUserRole`

The user is still **NOT** able to edit a step in the job to change some parameters. What am I missing?

More details 01:

I have Admin permissions on the BI box. A user needs to run a job when it is required & change configuration parameters when it is required. User is able to successfully run the job, but he cannot edit the step in the job. The button is called *View* instead of *Edit* when user looks into properties of the job.

Comment: how can you tell that user is not able to edit? you click and get some error? or maybe some button is missing? or...? please add some detail.

Comment: I have added more details. What is wrong with the question? I believe I was down-voted for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the answer on MSDN. User must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to modify the jobs that he/she did not create.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190948.aspx#Security

Comment: Warning - Giving sysadmin to a user mean they can do ANYTHING on the sql server.  This is not a good solution, unless you don't want to be a DBA anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below stored procedure to update the jobs in SQL Server Agent

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  

EXEC dbo.sp_update_jobstep  
   @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',  
   @step_id = 1,  
   @command = //your updated command ;  
GO
```

Source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobstep-transact-sql